# Does injectivity of $f:A\longrightarrow B\times C, f(x)=(g(x),h(x))$ implies the injectivity of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

If a function $f:A\longrightarrow B\times C, f(x)=(g(x),h(x))$ is injective, does it imply that $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ are also injective? I think this is straight forward but just want to confirm.

Suppose that $g,h$ are not injective. This means for some $x,y,x\neq y\in A$, we have  $g(x)=g(y)$ and $h(x)=h(y)$, that is $(g(x),h(x))=(g(y),h(y))\Longrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$, a contradiction since $f$ is injective.

Is this correct?

Comment: 1)  "Suppose that g,h are not injective."  What if one was but the other wasn't.   2"This means for some x,y,x≠y∈A, we have g(x)=g(y) and h(x)=h(y)"  Why.  Why would they *both* fail injectivity at the *exact same* values?  Take $h(x) = x^2$ so $h(-2)=h(2)$ and take $g(x) = (x-2)^2$ so $g(0) = g(2)$  But $g(2) \ne g(-2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your question should be about $g$ and $h$, not $f$ and $g$.
2. Your argument is mistaken. For instance, $h(x) = 1, g(x) = x$ makes $f$ injective, but $h$ is certainly not. See whether, looking at this counterexample, you can figure out what was wrong with your argument.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a contradiction.  If $g(x) = g(y)$ but $h(x) \ne h(y)$ then $f(x)= (g(x),h(x)) \ne (g(x), h(y)) = f(y)$.

That's possible.

.....

Example:  Let $g(x) = x^2$ and $h(x)=(x-2)^2$.  These are not injective.

But $f(x) = f(y)$ means that $g(x) = g(y)$ *AND* $h(x) = h(y)$.

So $x^2 = y^2$ so $x = \pm y$.  If $x \ne y$ then $x = -y$.

But $(x-2)^2 = (y-2)^2$ so

$x-2 = \pm(y-2)$ so either $x=y$ or $x-2 = -y+2$ and $x =-y+4$.

But if $x \ne -y$ then we must have *BOTH* $x =-y$ and $x=-y + 4$.

That can not happen so $f$ is injective.